# Java2OFG cannot find hashmap put call

Tags: rascal

My Program object from Java2OFG does **not** contain any hashmap `put` calls, but **can** find hashmap `remove` and `containsValue` calls.

```
p = createOFG(|project://eLib|);
println(p);
```

Shows:

```
call(|id:///|,|id:///|,|java+field:///Library/users|,|java+method:///java/util/Map/containsValue(java.lang.Object)|,[|java+parameter:///Library/addUser(User)/scope(user)/scope(0)/user|])

call(|id:///|,|id:///|,|java+field:///Library/users|,|java+method:///java/util/Map/remove(java.lang.Object)|,[|java+method:///Library/removeUser(int)/__param555_0|])
```

But no mention of any `put` calls, while put calls **are** present in the java code.

Comment: looks weird. pls check with your colleagues if they have the same issue?

Comment: Tip: `iprintln(p)` or `import util::ValueUI;` and then `text(p)` gives a better overview of the flow program for debugging purposes.

Comment: Maybe you use an different version of Rascal? The latest stable is advised for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, some methods are there, but others are not:

```
rascal>p = createOFG(|project://eLib|);
... 
rascal>cv = |java+method:///java/util/Map/containsValue(java.lang.Object)|;
loc: |java+method:///java/util/Map/containsValue(java.lang.Object)|
rascal>/c:call(_,_,_,cv,_) := p ? c : "bla"
Stm: call(
  |id:///|,
  |id:///|,
  |java+field:///Library/users|,
  |java+method:///java/util/Map/containsValue(java.lang.Object)|,
  [|java+parameter:///Library/addUser(User)/scope(user)/scope(0)/user|])

rascal>cv = |java+method:///java/util/Map/put(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)|;
loc: |java+method:///java/util/Map/put(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)|
rascal>/c:call(_,_,_,cv,_) := p ? c : "bla"
value: "bla"
```

So, these queries shows that the flow program indeed contains a call to containsValue but not to `put`.

While reading the code of `lang::ofg::ast::Java2OFG` it seems something special is going on with some of the methods in container classes. Instead of calls to put ending up as a `call` in the flow language, these method calls are transformed into assignments! This means that Java2OFG models flow into a collection using a special abstract symbolic variable, i.e. map's `put` method is modeled as an variable assignment and `get` as a variable lookup.

That's a correct model, and useful otherwise data would flow into the container API, for which we have no model of the internals, and would never come out again.

The algorithm missed edges from the key of a map to the receiver though, and also skipped flow from primitive types. A new version is published here: https://gist.github.com/jurgenvinju/60645058b6d0b0ccce0fc6f856da6ea6

Comment: We can also find the `containsValue` call, but not a `put` call.

Comment: I adapted the answer; so now we know what's going on. use the force, read the source :-)

Comment: We have found the assignment

`assign(|java+field:///Library/users|,|id:///|,|java+parameter:///Library/addUser(User)/scope(user)/scope(0)/user|)`

But this only gives us the assignment for the **value** and not the **key** of the map.

When we checked the source code of Java2OFG.rsc we found that indeed no assignment is made for the key.

How can we determine what the type of the key will be, without altering the Java2OFG.rsc?

Comment: Good analysis, and question. Let's think about this before we make a rash decision. Alternatives: add an assignment for the key, or, remove the whole special treatment and leave it to the user of the library (adds need to analyze Java ASTs), or, leave the old call relation in AND add the assignment for the value. What do  you think?

Comment: found some more issues. will rewrite Java2ObjectFlow a bit.

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/jurgenvinju/60645058b6d0b0ccce0fc6f856da6ea6